# How to connect to existing elastic beanstalk instance locally from cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very much new to **aws**. I have created an environment in elastic beanstalk and deployed my application there using zipped code. The application is up and running now. Now i want to `stop` and `start` my elastic beanstalk instance from **cli** in windows. I could not find any **stop** button in the aws elastic beanstalk console.

I have installed `awsebcli` using below command:

```
pip install awsebcli
```

Now, i want to connect to my existing environment in elastic beanstalk and stop or start the environment at my will.

How can i do that?

Comment: Why would you want to "stop" the environment? Elastic Beanstalk isn't really designed for that workflow, you could stop the underlying instance, but the point of elastic beanstalk is running things in production that are not likely to be stopped. If you are using it development, i would probably just do that locally or using a raw instance.

Comment: I am very much new to aws and i have deployed my dynamic website to elastic beanstalk. It's still in development. So, are you suggesting that i should deploy it to raw EC2 instance and test it there and when the final versions are out, then i should deploy it to elastic beanstalk?

Comment: How to stop the underlying EC2 instance? Can you please point me out that?

Comment: Found the EC2 instance that is being run by elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 1):

The way the EBCLI (awsebcli) works is that you associate an empty directory on your computer with an EB application.

1. go to an empty directory
2. `eb init --region <region name>`. When prompted for the application name, choose the application you created previously.
3. `eb terminate <environment name>`. This will terminate the environment.

To create a new environment, perform `eb create`.